# Safest way to automatically generate Java .class files from source, independent of build enviroment

Tags: java, gradle, build, compilation

This might sound like an odd problem, but I'm trying to generate .class files from a given Java project, in an attempt to automatically scan compiled Java code and find bugs.

The process goes like this:

- User requests scan of GitHub repo
- Script downloads repo (mainly Java code in this case), and in some way builds/compiles it.
- Script runs SpotBugs (or other compile-code analyzer) on the compiled code to find any errors or surface-level bugs
- Script reports results of scan back to user

Is there any way to guarantee a set of class files across different build tools? Some projects use maven, others gradle, and with gradle you're not guaranteed class files as output.

Any help / pointers much appreciated!

Comment: just curious, you're trying to make something like SonarQube?

Comment: Something similar, yes. Difference is, when using SolarQube you're likely the owner or stakeholder in a specific project, so you know how to build the Java source relatively easy. I'm essentially looking for a catch-all (or close to) method of building Java projects and generating .class files, regardless of deployment type.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think SonarQube build the Java project and thus only checks the source. Ideally you'd also analyse built code.